# sorted() extending the list so i cannot find median

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I run this code it adds to the list so I can't find the median. How would I make it so empty values do not get added to the list

```
import statistics
import time
amount=int(input('How many marks are you going to 
input? (most 10) '))
while amount>10:
    print('No')
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(amount)
    input_string=input('Enter marks of students 
separated by a space:   ')
    print('\n')
    user_list = input_string.split()
    print('list: ', user_list)
    user_list=map(int, user_list)
    print('Mean = ', sum(user_list)/amount)
    sorted_string=sorted(input_string)
    print(sorted_string)
    new=(amount+1)//2
    print(new)
    median=sorted_string[new]
    print(median)
```

Comment: `sorted` does not change the list in any way. It returns a new list

Comment: I don't understand how it adds blanks to the list though. When I run it it says
[' ', ' ', '1', '3', '4']
where the amount is 3 and input_string is 4 3 1

Comment: `sorted_string=sorted(input_string)` - you're sorting the string. Not a list.

Comment: Also, `user_list=map(int, user_list)` makes a non-reusable iterator, not a list.

Comment: ohh i see thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First issue

You are iterating through a map more than once, which leaves you with a bug of sorting an empty collecting.
(I suggest you read more about it: [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an [iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator))

to demonstrate the issue:

```
my_map = map(int, ['1', '2', '3'])

print('first run')
for i in my_map:
    print(i)

print('second run')
for i in my_map:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
first run
1
2
3
second run
```

#### Second issue

You are passing `input_string` to `sorted()` instead of `user_list` which is what I assume you want?

#### Example

Fixing (1) and (2) will result in the expected output:

```
import statistics
import time
amount=int(input('How many marks are you going to input? (most 10) '))
while amount>10:
    print('No')
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(amount)
    input_string=input('Enter marks of students separated by a space:   ')
    print('\n')
    user_list = input_string.split(' ')
    print('list: ', user_list)
    user_list=list(map(int, user_list))
    print('Mean = ', sum(user_list)/amount)
    sorted_string=sorted(user_list)
    print(sorted_string)
    new=(amount+1)//2
    print(new)
    median=sorted_string[new]
    print(median)`
```

dialogue:

```
How many marks are you going to input? (most 10) 2
2
Enter marks of students separated by a space:   100 95


list:  ['100', '95']
Mean =  97.5
[95, 100]
1
100
```

#### Side notes

Outside the context of your question, consider:

1. Taking the amount from the given list, instead of requesting for an amount explicitly
2. If the amount given is `>10`, then there is an infinite loop saying 'No'. Just making sure this is intentional.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that
also the loop is intentional I know that I can use if but i just preferred a looping 'No'

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to sort user_list and not input_string as currently it sorts the input string char by char:

```
How many marks are you going to input? (most 10) 3
> 3
Enter marks of students separated by a space:   90 100 90
> list:  ['90', '100', '90']

sorted_string=sorted(input_string)
[' ', ' ', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '9', '9']
```

Sort user_list:

```
sorted_string=sorted(user_list)
```

> list: ['90', '90', '100']

Will sort the input grades.

This should work for you:

```
import statistics
import time

amount=int(input('How many marks are you going to input? (most 10) '))
while int(amount)>10:
    print('No')
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(amount)
    input_string=input('Enter marks of students separated by a space:   ')
    print('\n')
    user_list = [int(x) for x in input_string.split()]
    print('list: ', user_list)
    #user_list=map(int, user_list)
    print(user_list)
    print('Mean = ', sum(user_list)/amount)
    sorted_string=sorted(user_list)
    print(sorted_string)
    new=int((amount)//2)
    print(new)
    median = sorted_string[new]
    print(median)
```

I commented the map method to keep user_list as list, and converted each input to integer in advance.

Also, new variable logic was wrong (amount+1), and was changed to amount//2.
Notice that it only works when the list length is odd.

To handle even lists:

```
new=int((amount)//2)
if len(sorted_string) % 2 == 0: # even length
    # do average of new and new-1
    median = (sorted_string[new] + sorted_string[new-1]) / 2
else: # odd length
    median = sorted_string[new]
```